# NuGet doesn't copy config file

Tags: deployment, build, package, nuget, nuspec

I've tried many different things now, none of which seem to work out as expected.

I would like to share an example config(or image or whatever) file with my library that someone would be able to use and derive from. I tried to default to just To do so I tried to include it in the nuget package via `*.nuspec` and via `*.csproj`. None of which worked.

For the `*.nuspec` part, I've tried this:

```
<file src="bin\$configuration$\example.mylib.config" target="lib\net45" />
<file src="bin\$configuration$\example.mylib.config" target="build" />
<file src="bin\$configuration$\example.mylib.config" target="bin" />
```

I've also tried this, but that only copies the file to the other projects sources, which is not what I want. I would like it to only show up in the output of the build.

```
<file src="bin\$configuration$\example.mylib.config" target="content" />
```

For the `*.csproj` part, I've tried to set the `build action` of the file to `content`, `resource`, `embedded resource` and `None`.

Is there a way at all?
Is there a way to tell `nuget`, take this file, and behave like the dll I'm providing needs this by it's side, wherever you build?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm facing the same issue.

Comment: @TheFiddler unfortunately not, but I have no idea why they left it out. The only way I see at the moment is to put it in a script and let the script print it. Which is somewhat the most dirty way to do it ever...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thought might be to perform a [config file transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/source-and-config-file-transformations#specifying-config-file-transformations). Rather than just deploying a config file directly, you could modify the `app.config` or `web.config` on the project with a sample for the user to apply. Alternatively, as you mentioned in your comment, you could add in a Powershell script to perform the manipulations you were considering.

Comment: A late answer, but I figured it might help someone else along the way.

Comment: thanks for still writing it down here. Although it might not really be an answer someone will be looking for, I'll mark yours as the answer in order to "close the case". Are you okay with that?

Comment: @Kjellski Yeah that works for me. If someone else has a similar issue, they can always raise a new question.